# How to get center coordinates of a label in SimpleItk

Tags: c#, itk

I am using the SimpleITK framework(x64) for C#.

After I do some operations and filtering I got a bunch of labels through the LabelShapeStatisticsImageFilter, where i am interested  in.

How do I get the center coordinates of a specific label ?
When I use the function `GetCentroid` I get partial negative results and I do not understand how to proceed with this data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the spacing and direction cosine matrix of your image? What is the Centroid value?

Comment: using GetOrigin(), GetSpacing() you can work out where the centroid is in space. look at the ITK Software Guide for tips on working in 3D (?) space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers and comments.

I found the solution to the problem in a comment of an example:

```
 // NOTE: As of April 8, 2015 the filter does not work with non-zero origins
```

So i saved the Origin data, set the Origin to (0,0) - got a useful Centeroid and altered the Centeroid result for the original Origin to finally set it again to its former value.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

**roi**, is an `itk image file`, the foreground value is 1.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
foreground_value = 1
label_statistic = sitk.LabelIntensityStatisticsImageFilter()
label_statistic.Execute(roi == foreground_value)
center_gravity = label_statistic.GetCenterGravity(1)
center_gravity_coordiate = roi.TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(center_gravity)
```

Comment: This does not work, sitk.LabelIntensityStatisticsImageFilter needs original image and label image. You should still use LabelShapeStatisticsImageFilter.

Answer (score 0):

The `LabelShapeStatisticsImageFilter::GetCentroid` method returns a point in physical space and not in index space. This takes into consideration the Image's Origin, Spacing, and Direction matrix which may result in negative values. To convert the result to index space you can use `Image::TransformPhysicalPointToContinuousIndex` or `Image::TransformPhysicalPointToIndex` as appropriate.